# Porting Crystal Report from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

I have done a tonne of work in porting quite a large VB6 project over to .NET but have hit a snag on the crystal reports. I've converted the dsr files to rpt. The next stage is getting it into the code

The VB6 way was to use the following

```
Dim report As New cryMyReport
```

Even after importing the rpt files into the project, `cryMyReport` is not recognised.

What do I need to do to get my .NET app recognise and use the rpt files?

Comment: is cryMyReport possibly a class in your own project that is used to create crystal reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often refer people to http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_step_by_step.htm

Essentially you need to add the Crystal references (you will need the Crystal reports for visual studio runtimes installed), add a CrystalReportViewer and then use some code along the lines of:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
        cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```